# shuffling a list multiple times

Tags: java, android, list, shuffle

I have 2 lists that I shuffle at the beginning of my oncreate() and then I would like to shuffle them again at a later point when a "new game" button is pressed. The first time they are shuffled I used:

```
final Random rnd = new Random();
final int seed = rnd.nextInt();

rnd.setSeed(seed);
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(answerChoices),rnd);
rnd.setSeed(seed);
Collections.shuffle((resources),rnd);
```

And everything works fine. However when I try to shuffle them again when a "new game" button is pressed i tried using the same as above and I tried changing the name of both rnd and seed and it doesnt work properly. After the second shuffle the lists do not match as they should. any suggestions as to what I should try?

Comment: What do you mean by `the lists do not match as they should`?

Comment: the lists do get shuffled the second time but they dont match. the first time they are shuffled they match. by match i mean row 0 of list 1 should always correspond to row 0 of list 2 no matter where they get switched to after being shuffled.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you are randomly shuffling two lists but expect them to have the same result? This seems very risky as the behavior of `shuffle` should not be relied upon to be repeatable. I suggest you use another mechanism such as shuffling one list a copying it or doing your own shuffle of both lists concurrently.

Comment: In my testing it has been reliable, the only times I have run into issues is when shuffling it a second time. The biggest problem I am having is that my second list contains references to drawable resources so it must be an int list and the first contains char sequences. I would like to have 1 list with everything but I dont think it would be possible.

Comment: I think you need to do a bit of refactoring to be "tie" the two different resources. I know that's not the question, but it avoids scenarios like this.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I think that's what he wants though--the same result from subsequent shuffles.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see what you're trying to do now. You're assuming that the built-in collections.shuffle() will do the same thing twice if you seed the RNG the same. There's no reason to believe that. Do the shuffle yourself, and just swap elements in both arrays in side the loop. Also, seeding an RNG from the results of the same RNG is just as nad as reseeding it from something like a time source--there are still possible correllations to worry about.

Comment: thanks for the information everybody. I am going to try to avoid shuffling twice, it may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution to your problem is to wrap the values in your two lists in a class. Then add objects of those class to one list and shuffle that, for example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int seed = rnd.nextInt();
        rnd.setSeed(seed);
        List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();

        pairs.add(new Pair(1, "else"));
        pairs.add(new Pair(2, "bar"));
        pairs.add(new Pair(3, "pair"));

        Collections.shuffle(pairs, rnd);

        for (Pair pair : pairs) {
            System.out.println(pair.drawable + " " + pair.sequence);
        }
    }

}

class Pair {
    int drawable;
    CharSequence sequence;

    Pair(int drawable, CharSequence sequence) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
        this.sequence = sequence;
    }
}
```

Running the code repeatedly will result in different ordered lists, but the values will still be paired.